# import org.json does not exist error in java transformation

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to edit an existing java transformation in a mapping. I'm getting a compilation error.

> org.json does not exit.

How can I fix this?

Note: This is occurring in existing code. I just changed the output column length in output port.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include both more of the error, and also the code that it references.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that sometimes when I edit an existing Java transformation, I lose any jar files I've added to the classpath. In this case you need to go back to the Java transformation, click the Settings link underneath the code tabs. This will bring up a list of jar files that are being used. If the one that contains the org.json package (org.json.jar) isn't listed then you need to re-add it. Click Browse, navigate to the location of the missing jar file, then click the Add button. Compile and save and the error should go away.